# How to convert ISO 8601 Date+Time strings from Firebase to `Date` values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have this firebase Timestamp dates:

```
time1: "2021-02-19T15:23:47.747Z"
time2: "2021-02-19T15:28:04.331Z"
```

and I need to convert these dates to normal dates. I want to do this in Javascript.
How can I do this?

Comment: Those **are** "normal dates"... . I assume instead that you mean you actually want a `Date` object and/or a localized formatted representation of those dates?

Comment: @Dai yes. something more human readable. also I need to find out their difference

Comment: What do you mean by "normal dates"? These dates that you have are in ISO 8601 format. If you would like to present them in more human friendly form, then you could use https://momentjs.com, which is one of best JS library for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can get ms timestamp with:

```
new Date(time1).getTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Date.parse()` to convert your string to milliseconds.  You can then convert that into whatever you need.

```js
const time1 = convertTimestamp("2021-02-19T15:23:47.747Z");
const time2 = convertTimestamp("2021-02-19T15:28:04.331Z");

function convertTimestamp(dateStr) {
  const start = Date.parse(dateStr);

  let now = new Date(0); // The 0 is important
  now.setUTCMilliseconds(start);
  
  const output = now.getUTCFullYear() +"/"+ (now.getUTCMonth()+1) +"/"+ now.getUTCDate() + " " + now.getUTCHours() + ":" + now.getUTCMinutes();
  
  document.body.append(output + '  ');

  return output;
}
```

Avoid the `new Date(dateString)` format as it doesn't have consistent behavior over different environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it like that:

```
new Date('2021-02-19T15:23:47.747Z').toGMTString().split(' ')
// ["Fri,", "19", "Feb", "2021", "15:23:47", "GMT"]
```

Or

```
let converted = new Date('2021-02-19T15:23:47.747Z').toGMTString().split(' ');
let date = {
    year: converted[3],
    month: converted[2],
    day: converted[1],
    time: converted[4],
    timezone: converted[5]
}

// day: "19"
// month: "Feb"
// time: "15:23:47"
// timezone: "GMT"
// year: "2021"
```